# How to use 'only' keyword to select which job to run when tag name ends with some specific keyword

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, string-matching, cicd

Although this seems to be very easy but seems like I am doing something silly somewhere. I am trying to automate my project where I have decided to run either of the jobs where one is for staging and one is for production. I want my `deploy-on-staging` job to run when my tag released ends with `-stage` and `deploy-on-prod` job to run when my tag release ends with `-prod`. For this I have used `only` keyword (instead of `rules` keyword as it was becoming pain for me). But only keyword is not supposed to be working as expected, for me.

The issue I am getting is even after using the `only` keyword, both of my jobs are still running. Any pointer would be very helpful.

I am just pasting the code of my gitlab-ci.yml which would be useful to you to resolve this issue. Please ping me if you want something else also from the gitlab-ci.yml file.

Here is my gitlab-ci section:

```
variables:
  TagName: ${CI_COMMIT_TAG}

deploy-on-staging:
  stage: deploy
  # rules:
  #   - if: '$TagName == "*-stage"'
  #   - if: '$TagName == "*-prod"'
  #     when: manual
  image: ubuntu:20.04
  # tags:
  #   - docker-executor
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
  script:
    - echo "It's here in stage"
    - echo "$TagName =~ '/^*-stage/'"
  only:
    - tags
    - "$TagName =~ '/^*-stage/'"


deploy-on-prod:
  stage: deploy
  image: ubuntu:20.04
  # tags:
  #   - docker-executor
  # rules:
  #   - if: '$TagName == "*-prod"'
  # before_script:
  #   - apt-get update
  script:
    - echo "It's here in prod"
  only:
    - tags
    - $TagName =~ '/^*-prod/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only/except are deprecated https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except

to achieve that you want with rules, just use this example

```yaml
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /-stage/i
      when: always
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /-prod/i
      when: never
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It is working, but what I can see is, when "-stage" is applied, "deploy-on-stage" job shows up in the pipeline interface, and hides the "deploy-on-prod" job and same vice-versa. I was expecting that "rules" will atleast keep the job on UI interface(which has when:never) of pipelines while not running it. Please correct me if I am expecting too much and "rules" work the opposite way only. Please let me know if you want screenshot of what I am saying(incase you are not able to get what I am trying to say)

Comment: yes, you need to hide that jobs that you do not want to. In that case, you need to create the opposite rule in the deploy-production stage.